# need help with limit of integral function

Tags: calculus, limits

The limit is:

[image]

where $n \ge 0$

I have to idea how to approach this problem.

I would like some advice on how to solve this limit.

Comment: What are your ideas? What do you know? Please tell us. Then it will be better to help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the limit is zero.  $\int_1^2(1-x)^{2n}dx=\frac1{2n+1}$ and the other part is bounded.

Comment: i am thinking about squeezing theorem , put that integral between two values, calculate the limits of the values then if they are equal thats the limit of the integral but so far no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Taking up one of the comments, notice

$0 \le \int_1^2(1-x)^{2n} ln(1+x^2) dx <  = ln(5) \times \int_1^2(1-x)^{2n}dx$

since over the range of integration both $(1-x)^{2n}$ and $ln(1+x^2)$ are both positive and increasing functions of $x$, with $ln(1+x^2) \le 5$. Then use that $\int_1^2(1-x)^{2n} dx = \frac{1}{2n+1}$, then take the limit $n \to \infty$.